# appending to existing sequence file

Tags: hadoop, sequencefile

In my use case, I need a find a way to append key/value pairs to the existing sequence file. How to do it? Any clue would be greatly helpful. I am using hadoop 2x.

Also, I came across the below documentation. Can anyone tell me how to use this to append?

public static org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Writer createWriter(FileContext fc,
                                                                    Configuration conf,
                                                                    Path name,
                                                                    Class keyClass,
                                                                    Class valClass,
                                                                    org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.CompressionType compressionType,
                                                                    CompressionCodec codec,
                                                                    org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Metadata metadata,
                                                                    EnumSet createFlag,
                                                                    org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options.CreateOpts... opts)
                                                             throws IOException

```
Construct the preferred type of SequenceFile Writer.

Parameters:
    fc - The context for the specified file.
    conf - The configuration.
    name - The name of the file.
    keyClass - The 'key' type.
    valClass - The 'value' type.
    compressionType - The compression type.
    codec - The compression codec.
    metadata - The metadata of the file.
    **createFlag - gives the semantics of create: overwrite, append etc.**
    opts - file creation options; see Options.CreateOpts. 
Returns:
    Returns the handle to the constructed SequenceFile Writer. 
Throws:
    IOException
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The [issue HADOOP-7139](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7139) now it's closed and from version 2.6.1 / 2.7.2 **It's possible to append to an existing SequenceFile** :)

(I was using version 2.7.1 and looking for append to a SequenceFile, so I downgraded to 2.6.1 because version 2.7.2 it's not still out)

Answer (score 0):

It's still not possible to append to an existing Sequence File.

There is an open [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7139) to work on that but it's still unresolved.